# How to remove unwanted overlapping in android

Tags: android, android-layout, overlap

I am trying to make an Android interface, but I have a little overlapping issue with the views.

Here is my code. It is in a Tab, but I cut the Tab-part away. If you need it, I'll add it.

**UPDATE: I forgot to write that I have a lot of TextView, not only one**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

                <!-- A lot of TextView as the one above -->

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/add"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:text="@string/add" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

And this is what it outputs. As you can see, in the bottom, the text goes behind the button, but I want to have them in two different layouts

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where are all the welcomes coming from?

Comment: I updated the code. I have a lot of TextView, but I write only one of them in the code to make it shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to position it relatively above the button.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ScrollView                
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout" //Add this
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text="welcome"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/add"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:text="@string/add" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I try it, but the button disappear.

Comment: Ok, then try the revised version.

Comment: This is why you don't use RelativeLayout.  The 'fill_parent' height on the ScrollView will mess this up.  You'll keep knocking away at it, and eventually get something that functions.  Or just use LinearLayout and weight.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RelativeLayout unless you absolutely have to.  Ever.  I know that's not a popular opinion, but that's what I tell everybody.

I assume you want the scroll to take up as much space as possible, then have the button at the bottom?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="welcome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/add"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:text="@string/add" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

I *think* you can dump the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView, assuming you only have 1 child (the TextView)

Comment: I forgot to write it, but as you can see in the image, I have a lot of widget (in the example TextView) inside the scroll view.

Comment: OK.  Just put a LinearLayout in the ScrollView

Comment: I changed my code example to include it (I had taken it out, but put it back in).  Anyway, this should produce the layout you were looking for.