# ScrollView overlapping EditText in Android v4.3 but not v2.3.4

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I've done a chunk of research but this is so strange that I'm compelled to post this question. I have a vertical LinearLayout with a custom view above a ScrollView above a single line EditText. The custom view has a fixed height of 10dp and the EditText has a height of wrap_content, so it's the height of the hint. The ScrollView has a weight of 1, so it should take up all the space between the two. I modeled this code after https://stackoverflow.com/a/7998024/852795.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.program.main.StatsBar
    android:id="@+id/mvStatsBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />     

    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/tvScrollMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true" >           
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/command_entry"
    android:background="@drawable/command_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:hint="@string/command_entry" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What's particularly strange is that on my phone, which is Android v2.3.4, it works perfectly - The ScrollView fills with text and then scrolls, all above the EditText. On my v4.3 tablet, however, the ScrollView overlaps under the EditText so that the last line of the ScrollView is always half obscured by the EditText. Any ideas as to what could be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the problem and you seem to have randomly put a margin of 10dp on this textview that doesn't show on Android 2.3 but it does on 4.0.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Problem solved! But what the heck? Why would the margin inside the TextView inside the ScrollView make the ScrollView overlap? Furthermore, it's the marginTop and not the marginBottom, which is more perplexing. Lastly, what changed between v2.3.4 and v4.3 that would make this happen? Those are a lot of questions, but I'm confused as to why this fixes the problem. Thanks!